# EWS Java API ItemView change default orderBy value

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm using the EWS Java API 2.0 in order to fetch items from a mailbox. Simply I need to know the Java equivalant of following C# code snippet.

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(50); 
view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
```

There is no method called `view.setOrderBy()` in Java API. How can I change the default value of itemview orderBy property? And what is the default value of that property? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you require is called `view.getOrderBy()`
The below code is the Java equivalent of the C# code snippet you provided:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(50); 
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
```